# stuck on a problem about sequential weak* compactness of finite borel measures on a sigma compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, weak-convergence, riesz-representation-theorem, borel-measures

I was working through a problem In a book on functional analysis. the problem is

Let X be a $ \sigma $ compact metric space such that the space of bounded real continuous functions on X $ C_b(X) $ is separable. If $ \mu_n $ is a sequence of finite signed Borel measures such that $ |\mu_n|(X) \leq 1 $ for all n. Then there exists a subsequence $\mu_{n_j}$ and a finite borel measure $\mu$ such that $$  \int_X g d\mu_{n_j} \rightarrow \int_X g d\mu$$ for all g $ \in C_b(X) $
It is obvious by using the separability of $ C_b(X) $ hat there exists a subsequence $\mu_{n_j} $ such that $$ \int_X g d\mu_{n_j} \rightarrow T(g) $$ $T \in C_b(X)^* $ However beyond this I can't figure out how to conclude the existence of $\mu$ in the general case without an assumption of local compactness or a tightness assumption on $ \mu_n $ Is the problem as stated false or am I being dense by overlooking something? Any help is appreceitated.

Comment: What is the quantor on $T$? There *exists* some $T \in C_b(X)^\ast$ or for all such $T$?

Comment: Look into the sequential [Banach-Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach–Alaoglu_theorem)?

Comment: The T is just an element of the dual space of $ C_b(X) $ that comes from the sequential Banach Alaoglu theorem

Comment: What book are you using? Is it accesible online?

Comment: If $X$ is metrisable and $C_b(X)$ is separable, $X$ must be compact.

Comment: Thanks that solves the question since now we can use the riesz representation theorem.

Answer (score 0):

We know $C_b(X)$ is a separable Banach space by assumption.
BTW, $X$ being metrisable plus this separability implies already that $X$ is compact, so I don't see why your text adds a superfluous assumption here..

The $\mu_n$ define a sequence in the unit ball of its dual, which we consider in the weak$^\ast$ topology. We define $j(\mu_n): C_b(X) \to \Bbb R$ by $j(\mu_n)(g)=\int_X g(x)d\mu_n$ and all $j(\mu_n)$ lie in the unit ball of the dual of $C_b(X)$.

By the *sequential* version of the Banach-Alaoglu theorem (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem), e.g.) we have a convergent subsequence in that ball, so some $T \in C_b(X)^\ast$ and some subsequence $j(\mu_{n_k}) \to T$, and the last integral condition just states the weak$^\ast$ convergence of that subsequence.

Then Riesz' theorem (plus compactness of $X$, see above) finishes the argument.

I think that's all there is to it.

Comment: I don't think it is true in general that the dual of $ C_b(X) $ is M(X) on a sigma compact space so while the sequential Banach Alaoglu part is true the problem is that this identification breaks down and is not generally true for general bounded linear functionals.

Comment: @SamuelMillard it *is* true that the maps defined by the $\mu_n$ are in the dual and the norm condition says they are members of $C_b(X)^\ast$ and that’s all I need. The Riesz like theorems say that *all* dual members are defined by measures in $X$ and we don’t need that at all.

Comment: Yes but the riesz like theorems that I know of insist we are either using $ C_c(X) $ the space of compactly supported functions or $ C_0(X) $ the space of functions that go zero at infinity. And normally require some sort of local compactness condition on our space X the only result that I know of that relates to $C_b(X) $, in this case, would only work If we had some sort of tightness condition on the sequence altough maybe there is a representation theorem I am unaware of.

Comment: @SamuelMillard I made the explanation clearer (IMO) so now you see I don’t use any form of Riesz. No extra condition required. The map $j$ is well-defined.

Comment: Btw I'm not saying the measures don't define bounded linear functionals they clearly do. Im saying the bounded linear functional we get from the sequential banach alaoglu theorem has no obvious reason to be represented by a measure  without some other conditions on the space X.

Comment: @SamuelMillard we don’t claim the existence of a measure but just of a $T$ in the unit ball of the dual. That’s a weak and true conclusion.

Comment: Yeah I get that and was aware of the sequential Banach alaoglu theorem before posting. my question was if this problem was false because it required that T was represented by a measure not that T existed but thank you for your answer it has given me a different view of the problem